# Rails: how to generate locale files for validations in my models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-i18n, activemodel

I have an existing codebase and I want to support internationalization for all the validations on the models. It should be as easy as adding the appropriate lines in each locale file like `es.yml` and `de.yml` in the format of

```
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            some_property:
              inclusion: 'must be one of [foo, bar]'
```

, except I have a lot of models and it'd take a very long time to comb through them by hand. Is there a tool out there that can go through my models and generate the appropriate lines for the validations in each model for me?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks ? Does it solve your issue?

Comment: @AntonTkachov thanks but not quite. It's basing its translations on my `en.yml` but my `en.yml` only has the handful of validation messages I put there by hand. It doesn't seem like this gem can go into each of my models to do a static analysis of the errors that can be raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you want to customize error messages for inclusion, you'll have to write them individually. Are you aware of the translations at https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale? These provide standardized error messages in a variety of languages.